Doubt from Weinberg regarding orthonormality of Lippmann-Schwinger in- and out-states
I am reading Wienberg: Quantum Theory of Fields Vol 1 and I'm trying to understand the argument that he gave in the last part of section 3.2,  regarding proving the orthonormality of the "in" and "out" states $\Psi^{\pm}_{\alpha}$. I have a two-part question regarding the last part of this section. Before I begin here is some background:
The last part of section 3.2 discusses how to show that the in and out states are orthonormal using the Lipmann-Schwinger equations.
Here we expand the dot product $(\Psi_{\beta}^{\pm},V\Psi_{\alpha}^{\pm})$ by using the relation $$\Psi_{\alpha}^{\pm} =  \Phi_{\alpha} + (E_{\alpha} - H_{0} \pm i \epsilon)^{-1} V \Psi_{\alpha}^{\pm} .$$ We then use this identity 1st on the right ket and then on the left and we equate the dot products and then use the completeness relation to obtain the relation:
$$\large(T_{\alpha\beta}^{\pm})^{*} - T_{\beta\alpha}^{\pm} = - \int d\gamma \,(T_{\gamma\beta}^{\pm})^{*} \, T_{\gamma\alpha}^{\pm} ( \, (E_{\alpha} -E_{\gamma} \pm i\epsilon)^{-1} - (E_{\beta} -E_{\gamma} \mp i\epsilon)^{-1})  .\tag{3.2.9}$$
For the next part of the calculation he mentions that we need to divide the entire equation by $(E_{\alpha}- E_{\beta} \pm  2 i \epsilon )$ and then simplifies the relation to:
$$ \large \left( \frac{T_{\alpha\beta}^{\pm}}{E_{\beta} -E_{\alpha} \pm  2 i \epsilon} \right) ^{*} + \frac{T_{\beta\alpha}^{\pm}}{E_{\alpha} -E_{\beta} \pm  2 i \epsilon} = -\int d\gamma  \left( \frac{T_{\gamma\beta}^{\pm}}{E_{\beta}-E_{\alpha} \pm i \epsilon} \right) ^{*} \, \frac{T_{\gamma\alpha}^{\pm}}{E_{\alpha}-E_{\beta} \pm i \epsilon} .\tag{p.116}$$
This is the result given on pg 116, however, I'm running into some trouble while calculating this.
This is my calculation:
$$\large(T_{\alpha\beta}^{\pm})^{*} - T_{\beta\alpha}^{\pm} = - \int d\gamma \,(T_{\gamma\beta}^{\pm})^{*} \, T_{\gamma\alpha}^{\pm} ( \, (E_{\alpha} -E_{\gamma} \pm i\epsilon)^{-1} - (E_{\beta} -E_{\gamma} \mp i\epsilon)^{-1})  .$$
expanding the denominators on RHS we get:
$$\large - \int d\gamma \,(T_{\gamma\beta}^{\pm})^{*} \, T_{\gamma\alpha}^{\pm} ( \, (E_{\alpha} -E_{\gamma} \pm i\epsilon)^{-1} - (E_{\beta} -E_{\gamma} \mp i\epsilon)^{-1}) = \large- \int d\gamma \,(T_{\gamma\beta}^{\pm})^{*} \, T_{\gamma\alpha}^{\pm} \frac{E_{\beta} - E_{\alpha} \mp 2 i \epsilon}{(E_{\alpha} -E_{\gamma} \pm i\epsilon)(E_{\beta} -E_{\gamma} \mp i\epsilon)}. $$
Now dividing by $(E_{\alpha}- E_{\beta} \pm  2 i \epsilon )$  on both sides we get the LHS as :
$$\large \left(\frac{T_{\alpha\beta}^{\pm}}{E_{\alpha}- E_{\beta} \mp  2 i \epsilon} \right)^{*} + \frac{T_{\beta\alpha}^{\pm}}{E_{\beta}- E_{\alpha} \mp  2 i \epsilon}.$$
Here I have simply inserted the denominator inside the bracket for the 1st term and absorbed the minus sign into the denominator for the second term
the RHS becomes:
$$ \large  \int d\gamma \,\left( \frac{T_{\gamma\beta}^{\pm}}{E_{\beta} - E_{\gamma} \pm  i \epsilon} \right)^{*} \, \frac{T_{\gamma\alpha}}{E_{\alpha} - E_{\gamma} \pm  i \epsilon}.$$
Here the division by the term $(E_{\alpha} - E_{\beta} \pm 2 i \epsilon )$ , the term in the numerator $(E_{\beta} - E_{\alpha} \mp 2 i \epsilon )$ is canceled and the minus sign is dropped. The remaining denominators are grouped into the brackets and hence I obtain the relation:
$$\large \left(\frac{T_{\alpha\beta}^{\pm}}{E_{\alpha}- E_{\beta} \mp  2 i \epsilon} \right)^{*} + \frac{T_{\beta\alpha}^{\pm}}{E_{\beta}- E_{\alpha} \mp  2 i \epsilon} = \int d\gamma \,\left( \frac{T_{\gamma\beta}^{\pm}}{E_{\beta} - E_{\gamma} \pm  i \epsilon} \right)^{*} \, \frac{T_{\gamma\alpha}}{E_{\alpha} - E_{\gamma} \pm  i \epsilon}.$$
Question 1: Where have I gone wrong here in this calculation?
Question 2: How does this relation prove the orthonormality of the in and out states?
